# limit_req_zone not working for /login route

Tags: nginx

I want to allow 10 requests / minute for each IP. There should be no delaying of requests and no burst. I strictly want to allow 10 requests / minute.

```
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=login:10m rate=10r/m;
limit_req_status 429;

server {
    location /login {
            limit_req zone=login nodelay;
    }

    # ...
}
```

But looking at my developer console, the limiting is not working as expected (all request are made within 1 minute). The 2nd request is already denied.

[image]

What I would expect it to look like (10 successful request and then 429 until the minute has passed):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on my reading of [the documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html) I suggest you try adding a burst parameter. You could try removing "nodelay" to see what happens as well.

```
limit_req zone=login burst=5 nodelay;
```